# Is WiredTigerPreplog journal logs required for restore?

Tags: mongodb, backup, snapshot

I am trying filesystem based snapshot backup for MongoDB. I make a list of files in the dbpath , acquire lock and then take a snapshot and release the lock. I notice that this file WiredTigerPreplog goes missing in the snapshot when compared to the list of files made before snapshot. Looks like new log gets created and old ones are deleted, by the time the snapshot is taken.Will this file affect the restore, if it goes missing in the snapshot ?
Will it cause any data loss?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Follow published backup documentation, test your backup, report results.

Comment: Sure. I followed MongoDB documentation only and tried the backup. What I am worried is this wiredtigerprep log, gets rolled over and new logs are created . Wanted to know the significance of this log and if it ll affect the restore.